Issues accessing RHEL 9 from tssh component on talend
When connecting to rhel9 server by tssh component on Talend i am facing below error :
Exception in component tSSH_3 (sample_ssh)
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to rn000159310:22
at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:805)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:595)
at ppc.sample_ssh_0_1.sample_ssh.tSSH_3Process(sample_ssh.java:325)
at ppc.sample_ssh_0_1.sample_ssh.runJobInTOS(sample_ssh.java:680)
at ppc.sample_ssh_0_1.sample_ssh.main(sample_ssh.java:529)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:78)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:281)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:761)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.ClientKexManager.handleMessage(ClientKexManager.java:123)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:941)
at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:510)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
I have tried connecting to RHEL7 its working fine but for only Rhel9 its giving error.
i can access ssh on server via putty but Talend is throwing error.
